# How to make editable field of CreatedBy in salesforce object?

Tags: apex, trigger, fields, user-profile

CreatedBy field should be editable for only Salesforce Administrator Profile. Is it possible ?
Please give me Solution of this problem.
Because My scenario is Whenever user will de-active by Salesforce Administrator then that user record should be assign to it's Reporting Manager (Reporting Manager is lookup field of user on user object(Hierarchical Relationship)).

Answer (score 1):

CreatedBy field is a audit field. so cant edit. if you really want this, you should contact salesforce team.

On workaround, you can create a separate field to track this.